# Show object with disabled Mesh Renderer in Scene builder

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject, meshroom

I'm using an object to trigger event, so its Mesh Renderer is turned off. But I want to see the object in Scene window anyway to be able to modify the level.

Here are my object's components:

[image]

**How can I make an object visible for development purposes?**

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Gizmos](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.html).

> Gizmos are used to give visual debugging or setup aids in the Scene view.

In your case try Gizmos.DrawMesh, or if it's a simple cube Gizmos.DrawCube.